# Boas praticas Fragment e Service

Tags: android, android-fragment

Entao pessoal a questão e a seguinte..

Eu tenho uma activity conectada a um serviço.

Eu quero iniciar um fragmento e esse fragmento ira executar funcoes dentro do serviço.

Qual seria as melhores praticas para executar funcoes no serviço ?
Algum exemplo ?

Comment: Poderia informar quais funções o serviço irá executar, para ajudar a entender melhor o problema? Outra coisa, manter uma activity acoplada a um serviço tem performance ruim, sugiro repensar essa arquitetura, talvez usando broadcasts.

Comment: @Piovezan, sério que não é bom fazer `bind` de `Service` em `Activity`? Tem alguma fonte pra reforçar?

Comment: @Wakim Só minha experiência mesmo. Causava lentidão em dispositivos _low_ e _mid-end_. Talvez fosse característica do aplicativo, que realizava acoplamento/desacoplamento das activities a um serviço ao longo do ciclo de vida das mesmas. Em todo caso, troquei por broadcasts e melhorou bastante.

Comment: Bem eu utilizo o service da seguinte forma.
Assim ao criar o service eu inicio uma nova thread que fica a cada certo tempo faz uma verificacao online.

Esse mesmo service tambem é encarregado de atualizar uma base de dados.

Assim que o service encontra novos dados ele insere na database e da um broadcast avisando o aplicativo caso esteja ativo para fazer a atualizacao com os novos dados.


O Fragment utiliza a conexao com o serviço no caso o bind para fazer consultas na database ( basicamente para ler as mensagens )

Comment: Não vale a pena dar uma olhada em Loaders (em vez de fazer bind)? Você teria um Loader + ContentProvider (ligado ao banco), quando o Service atualizar o Banco usando o ContentProvider, ele pode notificar o Loader e atualiza o Fragment automaticamente (por meio de callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

Existem vários pontos a se pesar.

Na verdade **@Piovezan** não é ruim, depende do que precisa ser feito.

Se você precisa executar funções independente das Activitys crie o serviço sem bind, assim mesmo com o aplicativo fechado o serviço vai continuar sendo executado.

Agora se você realmente precisa comutar informações da activity para o service ele precisa ser bind e não adicione um fragmento a isso apenas transmita as informações.

- O bind não é obrigatório mas garante que ao termino da activity o serviço também pare, no caso de dependência evita erros.

O problema de se usar Broadcasts é o tempo de execução que deve ser de até 10 segundos para não travar o aplicativo, logo não é viavél fazer isso a menos que a partir do recebimento você crie uma AsyncTask ou tenha certeza de que a execução não passará disso!

Comment: O problema dos 10 segundos é que após esse tempo o sistema mata o receiver. No caso usei broadcasts do serviço para a activity, e não houve problemas porque era só uma rápida passagem de informações. Não havia caminho inverso, da activity para o serviço, então não tive que me preocupar com isso, mas se o fizesse seria por intent.

Comment: Em ambos os casos o Broadcast não seria recomendado se não tivesse a certeza do tempo de execução. Como no seu caso você tinha certeza dessa informação, realmente não vai ter problemas.

Uma coisa que eu notei em dispositivos low quando você permanece ele desligado (off screen) por muito tempo na volta ele acaba levando mais tempo do que o habitual. Uma activity ou service que faça envio de broadcasts na Screen On vai dar erro. O que não ocorre sempre mas ocorre!

Comment: Um tempo após a tela desligar a CPU entra em sleep mode. Porém, tela desligada e CPU em estado de dormência são duas situações diferentes. Para o broadcast funcionar é importante que a CPU esteja acordada, o que não tem nada a ver com a tela estar ligada ou não, pois a CPU pode estar acordada mesmo com a tela desligada dependendo do wake lock que se use, ou quando chegam dados via rede móvel. O erro que você fala provavelmente tem a ver com a CPU não executar o broadcast devido ao estado de dormência.

Comment: Eu expliquei no outro post como defini o uso do serviço.

Comment: Isso se você usar Wake Lock. Não é recomendado pela própria Google a menos que seja realmente necessário. Uma aplicação básica não deve usar Wake Lock.